# Which one is faster GCM AES-128 or Curve25519?

Tags: elliptic-curves, gcm

As I know the symmetric encryption algorithms are faster than asymmetric encryption algorithms. But when I test GCM AES-128 and Curve25519 encryption time, I find Curve25519 is faster than GCM AES-128.
Is that normal?
Is GCM AES-128 slow?

By the way, I use these python libraries for the comparison:

- [PyNaCl for Curve25519](https://pynacl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/public/?highlight=curve25519) (using the `box`)
- [Cryptography.io for AES-GCM](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/symmetric-encryption/#cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers.modes.GCM)

I performed the tests with Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit on an Intel Core [i7-2640M](https://ark.intel.com/products/53464/Intel-Core-i7-2640M-Processor-4M-Cache-up-to-3_50-GHz) and ran the tests multiple times with differing input lengths.

```
The speeds for curve25519 are (1 kB):
Encryption 6.29425048828e-05 sec
Decryption 2.31266021729e-05 sec

The speeds for GCM are (1 kB):
Encryption 0.000115156173706 sec
Decryption 0.000576972961426 sec
```

Comment: The link is to NaCl which uses Salsa20 and Poly1305 for authenticated encryption.

Comment: It appears that the AES-GCM library uses [OpenSSL for AES-GCM](https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/blob/master/src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/aead.py), which means hardware support _should_ be enabled...

Comment: So my _feeling_ is that AES-NI and / or CLMUL (hardware features of your CPU to accelerate AES-GCM) are not properly utilized here. However I couldn't confirm it looking at the code. Can you perhaps post the speeds you measured on your machine for both algorithms?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not just using Curve25519. You are using a Python wrapper to NaCl, which is a high level crypto library that uses Curve25519 for Diffie-Hellman computation to derive a secret value. This secret is then used to encrypt with a particular algorithm, defaulting to Salsa20/Poly1305. So this library performs *hybrid cryptography*, where the data itself is encrypted with a fast, authenticated stream cipher. Although functionally the API is high level, execution certainly isn't: it's a highly focused, minimal implementation that is focused on both speed and security.

The cryptography library on the other part uses OpenSSL to speed up AES-GCM implementations. If a high enough OpenSSL library is used then AES-NI as well as CMUL for the GMAC operations *should* be available on high end CPU's that support it. However, it is completely possible to use an older library or one that isn't compiled for AES-NI. OpenSSL is an old *generic* library that may also have some more overhead; it isn't targeted forspeed in the same way that NaCL is.

If you have larger messages then the speed difference is simply due to speed differences in implementation of Salsa20/Poly1305 and AES in GCM mode. Salsa20 is a fast stream cipher, while GCM mode can generally be accelerated by hardware.

---

Beware that testing for speed is particularly tricky, especially on higher level languages. Differences in startup time of the compiler parser may already influence the results. You need a loop for the startup time and a loop for the testing. Both loops should contain the algorithm.

Also note that the random number generation may be pretty different on each platform.

Comment: Happy to upvote answers that contain more specific knowledge about the difference. Unfortunately, doing the testing myself is going to be a bit too arduous.

Comment: So it turns out that a) OP probably used `python` which compiles to bytecode and then _only interprets said bytecode_ (and doesn't actually JIT compile it to machine code) and b) the variance on these measurements is probably quite extreme especially if you consider that the AES-GCM decryption took _5 times as much time_ as the encryption, even though it's (nearly) the exact same operations that need to be performed.

Comment: Yeah, the differences are pretty small. I do think that NaCl uses less instructions to achieve the same thing; OpenSSL has a lot of configurations (engine choices, specialized memory management etc.) but even simply calling the random number generator could already explain the differences for such small tests.